# Column with PK constraint contains null values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We are using postgres version 9.3 in our production databases.
We found that some of them contain null values ​​in a column that has a PK constraint. In a given table, there were 53 null-value records in a column with PK. We found the same problem with some columns with constraint NOT NULL. We found the inconsistency when we tried to update an column of the table that has this problem and received an error message regarding the constraints. How can data be inconsistent if constraints exist? Is this a postgres bug or some kind of database corruption?

Comment: This is not possible...

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version? `select version();` will tell you

Comment: One db uses 9.3.6, another uses 9.3.25.

Comment: You realize 9.3.x are not supported any longer (EOL Nov 2018). I would suggest updating as soon as convenient. However, the situation you describe can arise if the [NOT VALID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-altertable.html) option is used creating the constraint.  (At least for FK and check -includes not null). This generally occurs when the DBA or dev team doesn't want take the time to correct invalid existing data when the constraint is added. You need to post DML and select to show for PK. That would be a bug but never before reported,  seems unlikely.